# What are Snow Leopard's new features?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

I heard the final Snow Leopard release is now available. What are the new features?
What is changed from older versions? Can I install this in my non Mac desktop or laptop? If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the info ever needed:

http://www.apple.com/macosx/

Comment: can i install this in my non mac desktop or laptop ?

Comment: No. It is not licensed for that.

Comment: Legally, no, you're not allowed.